# Condition query result limit based on table data in sequelize and mysql

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Using sequelize.js with MySQL.
let's say I have a table with these columns:

```
id: number (PK)
name: string
isRead: boolean
createdAt: Date
```

I'm looking for a way to build the seqeulize options object, to represent an SQL query that will accomplish the following:

if there are more than 30 unread rows bring me all of those, sorted by createdAt descending.
otherwise, just bring me the latest 30 rows regardless of isRead, sorted by createdAt descending.

is this even possible with seqeulize? would love to get a hint at the right direction, because my searches and seqeulize docs doesn't yield any results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
Project.count({ where: {'isRead': 0 }).then(c => {
    console.log("There are " + c + " projects!")
    if(c > 30) return Project.findAll({order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]});
    else return Project.findAll({limit: 30, order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]});
})
```

Comment: this is an option thanks, but I want to minimize query round trips. here I have to 'talk' with the DB twice. is there any way we can achieve this with one query? i.e- make the DB implement this if-else logic?